# How to use Gaussian interpolation?

Tags: math, 3d, interpolation

So in a three-dimensional plane, I have 3 or more points at any given x, y or z and I want to draw a straight line between these, but the major problem I'm facing is that I want to have the option to make a "smooth path" between them. I heard about Gaussian interpolation, but don't know how to use it. A good alternative could work as well. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rf8D.png Hopefully, this image I drew makes it a little clearer. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make "smooth path", you need to build some curve, gaussian intepolation is not for this purpose.

You can calculate Catmull-Rom splines - simple way to build a set of smoothly connected curves. `Arbitrary example` - you just need to calculate three components in 3D.

Anothe way - use Bezier curves  smoothing [as described here](http://www.elvenprogrammer.org/projects/bezier/reference/index.html)

---

I can suppose that author applies [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) to get values in intermediate points t as weighted sum of base points t1..t3

```
X(t) = G(t, t1) + G(t, t2) + G(t, t3)
```

where

```
G(t, tx) = 1/(sigma*sqrt(twopi)) * exp(-((t - tx)/sigma)^2/2)
```

Comment: In my search to find something which I could use I stumbled upon Bezier curves as well. The only thing is it looked rather difficult to implement and I was hoping to find something simpler. I might be able to figure out Catmull-Rom splines, but I would really like to know if what you said about gaussian interpolation really is true. Since in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pm07D9bUktQ&t=450s at 7:08 he starts explaining that he used gaussian interpolation. Basically what I am trying to achieve is exactly what he has except in the minecraft engine itself and not a modpack.

Comment: If you have many inexact points with coordinate noise, you can smooth them using Gaussian smoothing ([diminish noise](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/An-instance-of-gaussian-smoothing-of-a-noisy-signal-by-using-the-described-model_fig1_45871864) - here positional noise), but I understand that you have few points and  want to draw smooth curve rather than straight segments

Comment: I'd like to draw anything in-between as well. The guy in the video only used 3 points and drew straight lines between them in a 3d plane. Then he used "Gaussian interpolation" and was able to make the path either smooth and rounded or straight and anywhere in between.

Comment: I added an assumption (not sure without textual description)